# Global Array in a class initialized size based on a pass parameter issue

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have a class called `matrixDec` (see code below), and what I want to do is to pass 2 variables into the constructor, then use those variables to initialize an array with dimensions `matrix[row][col]`. The issue I have is I get an out of bound error when a run my program. I suspect it's because when I call the class `matrixDec` both integers row and col (the global versions) are initialized with `null` or `0` before the constructor is even called so the array starts either `0,0` or `null, null`.

So now, I want the array to be able to be manipulated all throughout my class and I want it with dimensions `row, col`

```
private int row;
private int col;    
private String matrix[][] = new String[row][col];

//constructor for calss matricDec
public void matrixIni(int row, int col){
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;

    //matrix[1][1] = "test";
    //System.out.println(matrix[1][1]);
}
```

Comment: Note that `public void matrixIni(int row, int col)` is not a constructor, its a class method. In Java, constructors doesn't have a return type.

Comment: ohh I remeber now. its been a few years thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the array inside the constructor, not when you declare it. Like this:

```
public class matrixIni {
    private int row;
    private int col;    
    private String matrix[][];

    //constructor for calss matricDec
    public matrixIni(int row, int col){
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        matrix[][] = new String[row][col]

        //matrix[1][1] = "test";
         //System.out.println(matrix[1][1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize `matrix` there, because `row` and `col` haven't had their values assigned yet, so they're the default `0`.

Initialize the `matrix` in the constructor too with

```
this.row = row;
this.col = col;
matrix = new String[row][col];
```